# For loop inside another for loop to make new set of vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, for-loop, matrix

I would like to use a for loop within a `for` loop (I think) to produce a number of vectors which I can use separately to use `polyfit` with.

I have a 768x768 matrix and I have split this into 768 separate cell vectors. However I want to split each 1x768 matrix into sections of 16 points - i.e. 48 new vectors which are 16 values in length. I want then to do some curve fitting with this information.

I want to name each of the 48 vectors something different however I want to do this for each of the 768 columns. I can easily do this for either separately but I was hoping that there was a way to combine them. I tried to do this as a for statement within a for statement however it doesn't work, I wondered if anyone could give me some hints on how to produce what I want. I have attached the code.

`Qne` is my 768*768 matrix with all the points.

```
N1=768;
x=cell(N,1);

for ii=1:N1;
   x{ii}=Qnew(1:N1,ii);
end 

for iii = 1:768;
   x2{iii}=x{iii};
    for iv = 1:39
    N2=20;        
    x3{iii}=x2{iii}(1,(1+N2*iv:N2+N2*iv));
    %Gx{iv}=(x3{iv});
    end     
end
```

Comment: Is your code Matlab/Octave code?  If so, then consider tagging your question *matlab.*

Comment: Thank you very much. It's MATLAB. Thanks for the advice. This is the first time I've used this website. :)

Comment: What is exactly the problem? btw I notice one error - in the line `xr{iii}=...` you should check that the index is in the range (it should be maximal 768?)

Comment: ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> heightmatrixworkingchange at 333
    x3{iii}=x2{iii}(1,(1+N2*iv:N2+N2*iv));

The error I get is shown above. I wanted to know the best way to split each vector into small vectors within each of the 768 vectors. I want to know where each vector lies for future use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a normal 2D matrix for your inner split.  Why?  It's easy to reshape, and many of the fitting operations you'll likely use will operate on columns of a matrix already.

```
for ii=1:N1
    x{ii} = reshape(Qnew(:, ii), 16, 48);
end
```

Now `x{ii}` is a 2D matrix, size 16x48.  If you want to address the jj'th split window separately, you can say `x{ii}(:, jj)`.  But often you won't have to.  If, for example, you want the mean of each window, you can just say `mean(x{ii})`, which will take the mean of each column, and give you a 48-element row vector back out.

Extra reference for the unasked question:  If you ever want overlapping windows of a vector instead of abutting, see `buffer` in the signal processing toolbox.

Editing my answer:

Going one step further, a 3D matrix is probably the best representation for equal-sized vectors.  Remembering that `reshape()` reads out columnwise, and fills the new matrix columnwise, this can be done with a single reshape:

```
x = reshape(Qnew, 16, 48, N1);
```

x is now a 16x48x768 3D array, and the jj'th window of the ii'th vector is now `x(:, jj, ii)`.

Comment: Thanks very much. That works well. However I have one more question, can I then read these new vectors into a polyfit curve? I want to curve fit every section of my matrix - each individual length 16 matrix for each of the 768 rows.  Thanks :)


for ii=1:N1;
   x{ii}=reshape(Qnew(:,ii), 16, 48);
   
    for iii=1:48; 
            Gx{ii}=x({iii});
            Gy=[1:16];
           
        pr{ii}=polyfit(Gx{ii},Gy,2);
        
    end
end

Comment: I've already given you the code to refer a single window from the big structure: x{ii}(:, jj) Note I'm using jj instead of iii, which is too confusing.  You'll also need to think and write more carefully, using the same sort of indexing, about where you want to put your outputs.

Comment: Ok thanks. I had posted that before I got your updates. Thanks very much for all your help.